# Every graph $G = (V,E)$ that has at least one vertex $v$ with degree $d(v) = n$ must also have $|V|\geq  n + 1$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every graph $G = (V,E)$ that has at least one vertex $v$ with degree $d(v) = n$ must also have $|V|\geq n + 1$.

If degree is $n$, so there are one vertex connected with $n$ vertex, so there are $n+1$ vertices.. but how to prove in detail?

Prove that every graph $G=(V;E)$ where $\forall v \in V$, $d(v)\geq|V| -3$ and $|V| >4$ is connected.

I think that since $d(v) >1$, so each pair of vertices has a least one edge, so there are at least $n-1$ edges, so the graph is connected

Comment: What does the symbol $\square$ mean???

Comment: What do you mean by "$|V|\ge\square n+1$"?????

Comment: @bof I'm not seeing that box.  All I see is that $\left| V \right| \ge n+1$

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to complicate the first part of this question. If a vertex $v$ has degree $n$ then there are at least $n$ vertices distinct from $v$ and therefore there are at least $n+1$ vertices.

For the second question, suppose there are at least two components. Each component satisfies the result stated above and so has at least $|V|-3+1=|V|-2$ vertices. Then $2(|V|-2) \le |V|$ and so $|V| \le 4$. This contradiction proves that the graph is connected.

Comment: why 2(|V|−2)≤|V|?

Comment: Each component has at least |V|-2 vertices and there are only |V| vertices in total.